# Long line is connected and compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, ordinals, connectedness

How to prove that the long line is connected and compact. I was trying  to prove connectedness using contradiction but couldn't.

Comment: Page 159 of Munkres. Exercies 12*. Thanks for asking it.

Comment: Long line is really compact?

Comment: @tetori It's normal, but not paracompact.

Comment: What is "the long line"?

Comment: @AndréCaldas: It is the space $\omega_1\times[0,1)$ in the lexicographic order topology, with its lease element removed.

Comment: @CameronBuie Maybe it depends on what you mean, but normally I'd define the long ray as $\omega_1 \times [0, 1)$ in the lexicographic order topology, and then define the long line by putting two long rays together in the obvious way. What you described (the "open long ray") is not the same thing. To manisha: it's not compact, but it is locally compact. It has of course a compactification (by adjoining two points at the ends, with an appropriate topology).

Comment: @user43208: The definition I use is (a slight adaptation of) the one given in Munkres's "Topology." Yours is a fair definition, too.

Comment: @CameronBuie Indeed you do; I just looked it up in Munkres's book. The difference between the two definitions is arguably not that important I guess, considering that the basic uses in constructing topological counterexamples would be about the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually show that the long line is path-connected, which shows that it is connected. Pick any two points $x=\langle\alpha,s\rangle$ and $y=\langle\beta,t\rangle$ on the long line, with $x<y$. If $\alpha=\beta,$ then $s<t$ and the long line interval $[x,y]_L$ is readily homeomorphic to the real interval $[s,t]_{\Bbb R}$, so $x,y$ are connected by a path. Otherwise, $[x,y]_L$ is the disjoint union of (in increasing order) $\alpha\times[s,1)$, then a well-ordered (at most) countably-infinite set of intervals of the form $\gamma\times[0,1)$ with $\alpha<\gamma<\beta,$ then $\beta\times[0,t],$ joined end to end. You should again be able to show an explicit homeomorphism with a closed real interval, so that $x,y$ are connected by a path. I leave the finite case to you.

As a hint for how to tackle the infinite case, suppose that $A$ is a countably-infinite set well-ordered by $\prec,$ with $s(a)$ the immediate successor of $a$ in $\langle A,\prec\rangle$ for any non-maximum $a,$ and that $f:À\to\Bbb Z^+$ is any bijection. A ready proof by recursion shows that for all $a\in A,$ $$g(a)=1+\sum_{b\prec a}2^{-f(b)}$$ is an element of $[1,2)_{\Bbb R},$ so that $g:A\to [1,2)_{\Bbb R}$ is a function. Moreover, $g$ is readily an increasing function, and it can be shown that for all $c<2,$ there is some $a\in A$ such that $c<g(a).$ Thus, $$[0,1)_{\Bbb R}\cup\left(\bigcup_{a\in A}\Bigl[g(a),g\bigl(s(a)\bigr)\Bigr)_{\Bbb R}\right)\cup[2,3]_{\Bbb R}=[0,3]_{\Bbb R}.$$ Using these facts, one can define an explicit bijection $[x,y]_L\to[0,3]_{\Bbb R}.$

However, the long line is *not* compact. For example, let $z$ be the deleted least element of the long line, and for each $\alpha<\omega_1,$ let $z_\alpha=\langle\alpha,0\rangle.$ Then the set of long line intervals $(z,z_\alpha)_L$ forms an open cover of the long line with no finite subcover (possibly not even a countable subcover, but that is not known). It is, however, locally compact, as every element is contained in a non-degenerate closed long line interval homeomorphic to a closed and bounded real interval.

Comment: $L := \omega_1 \times [0,1)$ in the order topology is path connected, but not compact. $L^*$, the one-point compactification of $L$, is however *not* path connected. $0$ cannot be joined with $\infty$ by a continuous path. It is "too far away"

Comment: That's hilarious! It's worth noting that $L^*$ *is* connected, however, since $L$ is connected and dense in $L^*$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks...

Comment: @manisha: No problem. Let me know if you get stuck along the way of constructing your homeomorphism, and I'll see if I can give you some tips to get unstuck.

Comment: Excuse me, can you explain why the map between $f : [x,y] \to [0,3]$ is homeomorphism? Explicitly, why $f$ is continuous at $(\beta,0)$? (Note that $f(\beta,0)=2)$ and $f^{-1}$ is cuntinuous at $2$? Thank you.

Comment: @Andrews To which map are you referring? From your phrasing, it sounds like you're quoting an assignment. I'd suggest asking a separate question, rather than use a comment.

Comment: @CameronBuie I asked a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3374232, thanks for your time.