# Connected Linear Graph not Path-Connected

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, cardinals

Given a set of vertices $\{x_\alpha\}$ whose cardinality exceeds $\aleph_1$, (assume the axiom of choice) connect each vertex with its successor by an edge, forming a linear graph. Choose two vertices $x_i$ and $x_j$ such that $card\{x|x_i \lt x \lt x_j\} \gt \aleph_1$. On one hand, it is impossible to construct a path corresponding to the edge path from $x_i$ to $x_j$, since there does not exist a continuous, surjective map $\mathcal f: \mathbf I \to \mathbf S$, from the unit interval to the subgraph $\mathbf S$ between $x_i$ and $x_j$. On the other hand, the graph is connected and locally path-connected, and thereby path-connected, so that there must exist a path from $x_i$ to $x_j$, a contradiction.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Is it a contradiction that this path-connected space contains points that cannot be connected by a path? -- I didn't state it clearly previously

Comment: This looks similar to the long line, or possibly the one-point compactification of the long line. See the comments to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/514931/29059).

Comment: @DanRust Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re essentially looking at the lexicographic order topology on $\preceq$ on $X=\alpha\times[0,1)$ for an ordinal $\alpha\ge\omega_2$. This $X$ is not locally path-connected: the points $\langle\eta,0\rangle$ such that $\operatorname{cf}\eta\ge\omega_1$ (and hence in particular the point $\langle\omega_1,0\rangle$) do not have path-connected nbhds. Thus, there is no contradiction.

If you take $\alpha=\omega_1$, so that you have a set of vertices of cardinality $\omega_1$, you’re looking at the [closed long ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_%28topology%29), which is connected and locally path-connected (and hence path-connected). If, however, you add a righthand endpoint, you have (up to homeomorphism) a subspace of $X$ (above), $\{x\in X:x\preceq\langle\omega_1,0\rangle\}$, with righthand endpoint $\langle\omega_1,0\rangle$. As noted above, this point does *not* have a path-connected nbhd, and indeed this space is not path-connected: there is no path from and $x\prec\langle\omega_1,0\rangle$ to $\langle\omega_1,0\rangle$. (As **Dan Rust** suggested in the comments, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514776/long-line-is-connected-and-compact/514931#514931) and the comments below it may be helpful.)

Comment: @Kevin: You’re very welcome!